# Perl to Python ( SQLite 3, SOAP )

Tags: python, perl, soap, sqlite

I have a problem with rewriting code from Perl to Python. 
The problem is that the code in Perl works but in Python doesn't work. I want Python code to do the same what doing Perl.
If that help i add show stack trace (interrupted by CTRL+C):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"../../../../../ABCD/ABCD/public_html/cgi-bin/Tip3/zad3.py",
line 22, in <module>
    server.serve_forever()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 236, in serve_forever
    poll_interval)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 155, in _eintr_retry
    return func(*args) KeyboardInterrupt
```

Can someone tell me what I do wrong?

**Perl Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use DBI;
use CGI;
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use SOAP::Transport::HTTP;

SOAP::Transport::HTTP::CGI
    -> dispatch_to('Project')
    -> handle;

package Project;

sub list {
    my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=zad3.db","","");
    my $sth1 = $dbh->prepare("select name,value from product");
    $sth1->execute();

    my @row;
    my $xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><root>";
    while ( @row = $sth1->fetchrow_array() ) {
        $xml .= "<product>";
        $xml .= "<name>".$row[0]."</name>";
        $xml .= "<value>".$row[1]."</value>";
        $xml .= "</product>";
    }
    $xml .= "</root>";

    return $xml;
}
```

**Python Code**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
import SOAPpy
import sqlite3

def Project():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('zad3.db')
    print "Opened database successfully"
    cursor = conn.execute("SELECT name, value FROM product")

    xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><root>"
    for row in cursor:
        print "name" + row[0]
        print "value" + row[1]
        xml += "<product>"   
        xml += "<name>"+row[0]+"</name>" 
        xml += "<value>"+str(row[1])+"</value>" 
        xml += "</product>"
    xml += "</root>"

    return xml

server = SOAPpy.SOAPServer(("localhost",8081))
server.registerFunction(Project)
server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Whats the issue? The stack trace you are showing is caused by pressing CTRL + C on the keyboard to kill the program. Did you try to actually hit the soap endpoint?

Comment: The problem is that the code in Perl works but in Python doesn't work. I want Python code to do the same what doing Perl, i showed stack trace only for help to solve the problem. What do you mean: " hit the soap endpoint" ?

Comment: How do you know it didn't work? Did you make a SOAP request to your service ("endpoint")? What error did you get?